# print A4 doc on letter us size using pdfbox

Tags: printing, pdfbox

I would like to print a PDF document created with A4 format on a printer that is using US letter paper.

First, my method to print the doc on a printer with A4 format.

```
        public static void printWithPdfBox(String strFilename) throws IOException, PrinterException
        {

            PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            System.out.println("Printer name : "+ job.getPrintService().getName());
            PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
            doc = PDDocument.load(strFilename);

            PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            attributes.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);

            job.setPageable(new PDPageable(doc, job));
            job.print(attributes);
        }
```

I tried to add this attribute but it is not working :

```
attributes.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
```

In the help of print method, it is mentionned :

> Note that some attributes may be set directly on the PrinterJob by equivalent method calls, (for example), copies: setcopies(int), job name: setJobName(String) and specifying media size and orientation though the PageFormat object.

If someone has a solution, I'll apreciate his help ;o)

Comment: Have you considered manipulating the page dictionaries in the loaded `PDDocument` (more exactly the mediabox and cropbox entries) to effectively have US letter pages to print?

Comment: No, I didn't find any information about this solution and I search in apache java doc for PDFBox but I found nothing. Do you have any example or web link to such kind of implementation ?

Comment: I don't have any code at hands but it is not too hard to implement. You have to iterate over the pages (`PDPage` instances) of the document (`doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages()`). For each you can read the current mediabox (and crop box, if present) using `findMediaBox` and `findCropBox`, change the rectangle to US letter dimensions, and store it using `setMediaBox` and `setCropBox` respectively.

Comment: The solution to use mediaBox is working fine.